# how to setup splash screen for ubuntu 12.04 with non-graphical mode

Tags: ubuntu, splash-screen

I have check the plynmouth is running and even have put my theme in /lib/plymouth/themes directory and changed the default.plymouth to tu.plympouth . This file is from my theme but has got no result.

Has also updated the initramfs file.

Comment: And in the boot.log file the message displayed is :: "send an event to indicate plymouth is up"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was with Grub setting so it was tackled by changing ==>
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"  and you may have to add this if it doesn't exist in your grub ===>
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=auto